# Firmware reverse engineering

Tags: arm

this question is a follow-up from this previous post: [Flash dump binwalk blank, low entropy](https://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/20348/flash-dump-binwalk-blank-low-entropy)

I need to reverse engineer a firmware from a very secure device. I was able to reverse engineer the PCB and create a JTAG connector, which I used to read the EPROM memory. I tried to binwalk and all other software techniques but they all failed to provide any lead to what is in the firmware.

I then tried to open the file in IDA, and I could translate all memory blocks into Assembly instructions. Is it possible that the firmware does not reside in any operating system, but instead is only a set of Assembly instructions?

If indeed is just a set of instructions, would binwalk point anything confirming that?

File has 256Kb.

This is the processor: STM32L 152CCT6

Comment: How could I view that previous post which now has a 404?

Answer (score 1):

Yep it could be just "bare metal" code without any OS or standard data structures which binwalk can carve.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds Like the device you are messing does not have a traditional operating system you are used to dealing with. Since its a STM32 it will be in ARM architecture and I am guessing you are using IDA freeware. Try Ghidra it supports ARM I don't think the free version of IDA does. You still aren't going to find a file system though if that's what you are looking for. More details on the device could be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

STM32 is a family of Cortex-M based microcontrollers with pretty limited resources, so they rarely use a rich OS like Linux but usually either a monolithic single-binary firmware based on a classic processing loop, or a compact RTOS (Real-time Operating System) such as FreeRTOS, ThreadX or many other options. You *might* find some basic file system or individual resources but it might as well be just all code with maybe some string constants or data tables.